# What is a good programming font that looks good through Remote Desktop?

Tags: fonts, remote-desktop, cleartype, consolas

I guess I've just gotten spoiled with Consolas working on my local development machine. But at work we do a lot of development remotely via Remote Desktop, where any fonts requiring ClearType look *awful*.

I mean, *look* at this:

[image: Screenshot of Consolas font on Remote Desktop]

Normally I'm not a big fan of Courier New, but in this scenario it beats Consolas, along with all the other otherwise great-looking programmer fonts I've found (which all seem to require ClearType or some other rendering effect that apparently isn't available through Remote Desktop, at least from Windows XP) hands-down.

Can someone suggest any high-quality fonts suitable for programming that will still look good through Remote Desktop?

Comment: I've never had this problem - what OS is the are you running (both locally and remotely) and what application are you developing in?

Comment: @Dave: locally: XP, remotely: Windows Server 2008. And we're developing using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I've never had a problem with Remote Deskop through XP, but then again I don't like Consolas or Courier New. Give Andale Mono (9pt) a try, see if it helps.

Comment: @Juliet: Well, turns out the *real* problem was just that I'm an idiot... that is a very nice font, though; thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow this guide - perhaps it's just a configuration issue:

http://www.ytechie.com/2008/12/cleartype-in-remote-desktop-with-xp.html

The above guide shows you how to do this for every windows OS supporting clear type.

Dave

Comment: Wow, I could've *sworn* I had tried those options before! Guess not... thank you very much for kindly steering me in the direction that should've been obvious.

Comment: No problem at all - I suppose it's only obvious if you know how. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Since i've found ttf version of [terminus](http://misc.nybergh.net/pub/fonts/terminus/ttf), i'm using it on windows boxes without *ClearType*.

Answer (score 0):

## Cause For Me

Missing windows desktop experience in server 2012

## Fix

I had this same issue until adding the missing feature 'desktop experience' in server 2012.

It looked terrible, just like your screen shots.

### Install Desktop Experience

To add this feature to server 2012 with powershell run the following command:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience
```

That completely fixed the issue for me in all browsers/fonts, hope it helps someone else out there.